# Database and user classes for my personal CMS

Tags: php, beginner, object-oriented, mysqli

I have written my own CMS for learning, and have included all of my core files below.

This is my first time playing with OOP and prepared statements, so I imagine there may be alot of changing. There is one problem I am having, when I try and check if a username/email already exists in the register function by using either num_rows or affected_rows, I get a non-object error for the two lines that are counting the rows.

dbc class (Database connection, functions, etc):

```
<?php
/**
* class dbc
* @package Core
*
*/

// Sanity check. Does this class already exist?
if(!class_exists('dbc')) {
class dbc {
    public function __construct() {
        // Make the constants class variables
        $this->host = host;
        $this->username = username;
        $this->password = password;
        $this->database = database;
        $this->charset = charset;

        $this->connection = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);

        // Database connection error?
        if($this->checkConnection() == false) {
            die('Database connection error! <br />' . $this->connection->connect_error);
            return false;
        }

        $this->connection->set_charset(charset);
    }

    // Close the MySQLi connection
    public function __destruct() {
        if($this->connection) {
            $this->connection->close();
        }
    }

    public function select($columns = array(), $table, $variables = '', $order = '') {
        // Are the required variables empty or equals null?
        if(empty($columns) || empty($table)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Set $order and $variables to false
        if($order == '' || $order == null) {
            $order = false;
        }else if($variables == '' || $variables == null) {
            $variables = false;
        }

        // Check if $columns is an array
        if(!is_array($columns)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Set $fields as an array
        $fields = array();
        // Individualise the array
        foreach($columns as $field) {
            $fields[] = $field;
        }

        // Sepeate all individuals with commas
        $fields = implode(', ', $fields);

        // Finalise the MySQLi query
        if($variables == false && $order == false) {
            $query = "SELECT $fields FROM $table";
        }else if($variables != false && $order == false) {
            $query = "SELECT $fields FROM $table WHERE $variables";
        }else if($variables == false && $order != false) {
            $query = "SELECT $fields FROM $table ORDER BY $order";
        }else if($variables != false && $order != false) {
            $query = "SELECT $fields FROM $table WHERE $variables ORDER BY $order";
        }

        // Prepare the query for executing
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);

        // Execute the query
        $stmt->execute();

        // Get the results of the query
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        // Set the results to a variable
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $results[] = $row;
        }

        // Return the results as array 0
        return $results[0];
    }

    public function insert($table, $variables = array()) {
        // Are the required variables empty or equals null?
        if(empty($table) || empty($variables)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Set both variables to an array
        $fields = array();
        $values = array();
        // Divide each value as a singular value
        foreach($variables as $field => $value) {
            $fields[] = $field;
            $values[] = "'" . $value . "'";
        }

        // Split the fields & values with commas - to follow the mysqli query format
        $fields = '(' . implode(', ', $fields) . ')';
        $values = '(' . implode(', ', $values) . ')';

        // Finalised Query
        $query = " INSERT INTO $table $fields VALUES $values";

        // Prepare the query for executing
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);

        if(false === $stmt) {
            return false;
        }

        // Execute the prepared query
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    public function checkConnection() {
        if($this->connection->connect_errno) {
            // Connection Unsucessful
            return false;
        }else {
            // Connection Successful
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function affected() {
        return $this->connection->num_rows;
    }
}
}

?>
```

Config (Core website settings):

```
<?php

// Database Connection Information (removed for security)
define('host', '');
define('username', '');
define('password', '');
define('database', '');

// Show PHP/MySQLi errors?
define('DEBUG_MODE', true);

define('charset', 'UTF-8');

define('default_user_group', '1')

?>
```

User class (Register, login, etc for users):

```
<?php
/**
* @package Core
*/

if(!class_exists('user')) {
class user {
    public function __construct() {}

    public function register($username, $password, $confirmpassword, $email, $firstname, $lastname) {
        if(empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($confirmpassword) || empty($email) || empty($firstname) || empty($lastname)) {
            return false;
        }

        if($password === $confirmpassword) {
            $dbc = new dbc();

            $hash = '_HG.g2Sxa.';
            $encryptpassword = md5(md5($hash . $password . $hash));

            $status = default_user_group;
            if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
            }else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            }else {
                $ip = $_SERVER['REMOVE_ADDR'];
            }

            $ip = ip2long($ip);

            $userData = array(
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $encryptpassword,
                'email' => $email,
                'firstname' => $firstname,
                'lastname' => $lastname,
                'status' => $status,
                'ip' => $ip
            );

            $createUser = $dbc->insert('users', $userData);
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Security

**SQL Injection**

You are completely open to SQL injection.

It is not enough to simply use `prepare`. The important part is that you should never put variables directly into the query. The query should only contain placeholders (either `:key` or `?`). The variables are then later bound to the query.

**Hashing**

`md5` is not good enough for password hashing, and it hasn't been for at least 15-20 years. It's broken, and it's too fast. Use bcrypt instead (PHP offers this via `password_hash`).

Additionally, a site-wide salt (also called pepper) is not enough. You want a per-user salt. Luckily, `password_hash` manages this for you.

### Misc

- `if (cond) return false else return true` can be written as `return !cond`.
- don't `die` in classes or functions. It makes it impossible for the calling code to recover. Throw an exception instead.
- nothing after `die` will be executed, so returning something afterwards doesn't make sense.
- why is your pepper called `hash`? It's quite confusing.
- passwords are hashed, not encrypted, so `encryptpassword` should be `passwordHash`.
- either use snake_case or camelCase, but don't mix both, and don't use neither (multi-word variables written in all lowercase are hard to read).
- if the password and the confirmpassword are unequal, you just silently fail.
- your error handling in general could be improved. For example, you do not check the result of an insert.
- things that are named the same should work the same. In your code, eg `variables` works very differently for `select` and `insert`, which will make using your code very difficult, especially as you have no documentation.